# File Input Not Returning Good

Tags: c++, input, fstream

Apologies to ask such a basic question but I really cant see why In3 is not good. I suppose there is something fundamental here which I dont know

Thanks in advance

the contents of the file "testIn1.txt" are: 
a b c
a

I am using MS Visual C++ 2010 Express.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream In3;
    ofstream Out3;
    In3.open("testIn1.txt", fstream::in);
    Out3.open("testOut1.txt", fstream::app);
    cout << "Is In3 Good? " << In3.good() << endl;
    cout << "Is OUt3 Good? " << Out3.good() << endl;    
    In3.close();
    Out3.close();
}
```

Comment: Does the file exist and can it be opened by the OS?  testIn1.txt should be in the same directory as the .exe

Comment: @jonsca: the two In and Out files are in the same directory so if the Out gets opened I would expect the In fiel to get opened as well

Comment: If you're in Unix, the case (uppercase/lowercase) of the filename must match the case of the actual file's name in the file system .

Comment: @Random Check where the output file is actually ending up.  Normally, unless you specify a working directory for your application in the IDE, then it uses the same as the .exe

Comment: @Emile Cormier: I am sorry Emilie, I am using MS Visual C++ 2010 Express. I should have mentioned this earlier - I will edit my question.

Comment: Perhaps some other process still has the file locked for use. Try rebooting.

Comment: @jonsca: I think you are right - it must be related to the working directory. Do you know how I can check the working directory in VC++??

Comment: @Random Under the project menu, select properties, C/C++, I forgot which subheading it's under, and I don't have it in front of me.

Comment: @RandomCPlusPlus - dude, be clear. Why don't you cut/paste the output of `ls -ltr` (or `dir` if you are in windows) of the directory containing the input and output files)?

Comment: @luis.espinal - I would do it if I knew how to. Sorry

Comment: *"Do you know how I can check the working directory in VC++??"* - this is one of those times where you should give readers some courtesy and use google. They are trying to help you, so the courteous thing is to respond in kind by showing some initiative in finding answers for yourself. Don't expect people to simply spoonfeed you every single question that pops up with every single problem. That's not nice.

Comment: @RandomCPlusPlus - *"I would do it if I knew how to. Sorry"*. No offense, but before you posted that answer to me, did you even made an effort to find out how to do it? Did you even **think** the possibility of searching on SO or google for how to do what I suggested, before you replied back telling me that you didn't know and that you were sorry for it? Don't be an invalid and show some initiative. **That is how you learn to do things**. There is a difference between being truly helpless with a problem and playing helpless (not caring) expecting others to fill every single blank space.

Comment: Mate I did search in Google. Please be assured that I dont post it here lightly and I appreciate the help of those trying to help while trying to ignore those trying to put people down. Many Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @schnaader- sure, I will. Thansk for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me (using MinGW g++ as a compiler):

```
C:\>echo a b c a > testIn1.txt

C:\>g++ test.cpp -otest.exe

C:\>test
Is In3 Good? 1
Is OUt3 Good? 1
```

Note that testIn1.txt should be in the same directory as the executable or you should give the program a path to the file. You can verify that you're in the correct directory if testOut1.txt is created after running the program (and wasn't there before, of course).

Some other things that come to my mind:

- Input file is locked (as Emile suggested). A reboot would help, you can also use tools like [WhoLockMe](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/) to investigate this further. Also, deleting or recreating testIn1.txt should give an error in this case.
- AFAIK, MSVC uses debug/release folders. Depending on the configuration that is set, you might run an older version of your program which can be quite confusing. Make sure you're in the right folder, probably delete old binaries and testIn/testOut files and check timestamps to be sure.

To get the directory your file is running in, try this code ([source](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/104069/507046#post507046)):

```
#include <unistd.h>
char *path=(char*)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
size_t size;
path=getcwd(path,size);
cout<<"current Path: "<<path<<endl;
free(path);
```

Note that MS compilers might complain about `getcwd` and/or `unistd.h`, try `_getcwd` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your program in both Windows and Linux.

**Case 1**

Either the file does not exist in Windows and Linux, or

**Case 2**

In Windows if the file exists there should be no issue, in Linux, if the `Name of File` is not entered in proper `Case/Caps`, then it may not open.

*The `good()` function returns true if none of the stream's error flags `(eofbit, failbit and badbit)` are set.*

Try to add this statement and see what you get:

`cout << "Fail " << In3.fail() << endl;`